# How to find the total values in a column which are less than that particular value in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column which looks something like this

```
Quantity
20
40
10
25
```

I need to get the total number of values in that column which are less than that particular value like

```
Quantity    Value
20          1
40          3
10          0
25          2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to itself on values less than the current value:

```
select a.quantity, count(distinct b.id)
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.quantity < a.quantity
group by a.quantity
```

Selecting `count(distinct b.id)` handles there being non-unique quantities and the lowest value (which has no rows to join to, so the join will return a null, which `count()` won't count).